# Which sorting algorithm works best on very large data set that won't fit in the main memory

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was searching on the Internet to find which sorting algorithm is best suitable for a very large data set. I found that many have an opinion that merge sort is best because it is fair, as well as that it ensures that time complexity is O(n log n) and quick sort is not safe: It is also true that variations of quicksort can also be not safe because the real data set can be anything.

If swapping of the two elements has negligible time cost, then why can't we choose heap sort as the best sorting algorithm in this case because it is in place as well as O(n log n)?

In case of Merge sort it requires another O(n) space; if the data is very large then we can't use this algorithm.

Which algorithm should be the best in this scenario?

Comment: "Very large" is pretty vague.

Comment: Mergesort on a linked list takes constant space and is still stable, so your concern about space may be invalid. It also works great on files and can utilize multiple processors.

Comment: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ has a fun display of some of the variables and tradeoffs involved.

Comment: @erickson Does it really use O(1) auxiliary space? I thought you needed O(log n) space to store the call stack.

Comment: @templatetypedef No, it's an iterative algorithm with O(1) space. Just a couple of pointers and a handful of counters.

Comment: @erickson Oh, I see. Using a bottom-up approach would give you O(1) space. I was thinking top-down.

Comment: Does "very large" mean "more than a human can keep track of, but still fits comfortably into the physical memory of the system I have", or "will fit into the virtual address space of a process, but is probably larger than physical memory and so will encounter a lot of paging", or "is bigger than will fit even in the virtual address space of a process"? You would likely pick a different algorithm for those three scenarios, at least...

Comment: I don't see where the original question asks about sorting a linked list, however for a linked list, the fastest way is to use an array of pointers to lists, with an array size of 24 to 32 pointers (HP / Microsoft std::stable_sort uses 26).

Comment: The memory overhead for merge sort can be cut in half by using a temp array of size n/2.  Sort the second half of the array into the second half. Sort the first half of the array into the temp array. Then merge the temp array with the second half of the array back into the array. This leave room for the data to be stored when doing the final merge.

Comment: If the objects to be sorted are large enough, you could do a merge sort on an array of indices (or pointers) to those objects. Then a variation of cycle sort with time complexity O(n) can be used to sort the array of objects in place according to the sorted indices. Quick sort does more compares, merge sort does more moves, so if sorting by indices, merge sort is usually faster. I'm not sure about heap sort. Merge sort is stable (original order maintained), while quick sort and heap sort are not.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's no one algorithm that's clearly the "best" algorithm. If there were, we'd be using it everywhere! Instead, it depends on a bunch of factors.

For starters, can you fit your data into main memory? If you can't, then you'd need to rely on an external sorting algorithm. These algorithms are often based on quicksort and mergesort.

Second, do you know anything about your input distribution? If it's mostly sorted, then something like Timsort might be a great option, since it's designed to work well on sorted data. If it's mostly random, Timsort is probably not a good choice.

Third, what kind of elements are you sorting? If you are sorting generic objects, then you're pretty much locked into comparison sorting. If not, perhaps you could use a non-comparison sort like counting sort or radix sort.

Fourth, how many cores do you have? Some sorting algorithms (quicksort, mergesort, MSD radix sort) parallelize really well, while others do not (heapsort).

Fifth, how are your data represented? If they're stored in an array, quicksort or a quicksort variant will likely do well because of locality of reference, while mergesort might be slow due to the extra memory needed. If they're in a linked list, though, the locality of reference from quicksort goes away and mergesort suddenly becomes competitive again.

The best option is probably to take a lot of different factors into account and then make a decision from there. One of the reason it's so fun to design and study algorithms is that there's rarely one single best choice; often, the best option depends a ton on your particular situation and changes based on what you're seeing.

(You mentioned a few details about quicksort, heapsort, and mergesort that I wanted to touch on before wrapping up this answer. While you're right that quicksort has a degenerate O(n<sup>2</sup>) worst case, there are many ways to avoid this. The introsort algorithm keeps track of the recursion depth and switches the algorithm to heapsort if it looks like the quicksort will degenerate. This guarantees O(n log n) worst-case behavior with low memory overhead and maximizes the amount of benefit you get from quicksort. Randomized quicksort, while still having an O(n<sup>2</sup>) worst case, has a vanishingly small probability of actually hitting that worst case.

Heapsort is a good algorithm in practice, but isn't as fast as the other algorithms in some cases because it doesn't have good locality of reference. That said, the fact that it never degenerates and needs only O(1) auxiliary space is a huge selling point.

Mergesort does need a lot of auxiliary memory, which is one reason why you might not want to use it if you have a huge amount of data to sort. It's worth knowing about, though, since its variants are widely used.)

Comment: +1. It gets even more interesting when more than one machine is involved, or when you have to consider data access time from disk or from the network.

Comment: @rcgldr The quicksort variant I'm referring to works by streaming the file contents through memory, maintaining a huge double-ended priority queue. When the queue fills up, elements that are too small are evicted and written to a "less" file and elements that are too large are evicted and written to a "greater" file. The ultimate queue contents and then written to a "pivot" file and then the less and greater files are recursively sorted. It's not as common as the mergesort variant, but it still works, I believe.

Comment: @templatetypedef - Wiki article [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). A k-way bottom merge sort can can use large sequential I/O's as mentioned in the wiki article, which helps reduce seek overhead on a hard drive, but in the case of a SSD drive, there's no real seek overhead (the internal layout is remapped to reduce write counts to specific areas), so quick sort may be a viable alternative, although it's not stable. It's not mentioned in the wiki article.

Comment: @rcgldr I hadn't thought about SSDs. As for quicksort, check out [this site](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c13/double.htm), which IIRC is also a book chapter.

Comment: @templatetypedef - The references I find for quicksort mention good time complexity of O(n log(n)), but not what log. For a k-way merge sort, the worst case time complexity is O(n logk(n)); and my guess is that if k == 8 or k == 16, it's going to be a lot faster than a quicksort. Also at mentioned in my comment after the original post, quicksort does more compares, mergesort more moves, and if sorting some type of structure by index or pointer, mergesort is usually faster than quicksort.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is too open-ended to be answered specifically.  There are a number of efficient sorting algorithms and each has its own strengths and weaknesses.  If you know your data, it is possible that an optimal efficiency algorithm (heap, quick, merge, etc) is not the right tool for the job.

For example, in a recent product, we were required to keep the bookmarks in a Word document sorted by their order of appearance.  The bookmarks could become unsorted due to editing of the document (copy, cut, paste) so after each of those operations it was important to resort the list.  In this case, bubblesort was the right answer even though it has a higher big-O complexity then any number of other algorithms.  The fact that the sort is efficient when the list is nearly sorted (which is usually the case in this circumstance) and it's an in-place operation meant that it was the right tool for the job.

Take a hard look at your data and read up on the various strengths and weaknesses of the well-known sorting algorithms and you'll be well on your way to answering your own question.

Comment: Thanx alot for your explanation i will definitely look for that