# Sorting algorithm choice

Tags: sorting, quicksort, mergesort, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I was wondering which sorting algorithm between bubble sort, insertion sort, merge sort, quick sort and selection sort is the worst to use to sort a list of 100 million elements if you have limited computer space and why?

Comment: Sounds like a comp sci homework question. lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234711/which-sorting-algorithm-works-best-on-very-large-data-set

Comment: What does limited computer space mean? Will the list fit in memory?

Comment: Yes the list would fit the memory @trincot

Comment: All of these sorting algorithms use O(1) extra space, except merge sort, which (in its standard version) uses O(n) extra space. So if computer space is not large enough to store that extra space, and external storage is needed, then merge sort will be the slowest, even though it has better time complexity than some of the other candidates.

Comment: It depends what you call a *list*: python *lists* are actually arrays which you could sort with quick sort with **O(log(n))** extra space and **O(n.log())** average time complexity. Linked lists should be sorted with merge sort with **O(log(n))** extra space and **O(n.log())** worst time complexity. selection, insertion and bubble sort all have average **O(n²)** time complexity, which is too slow for lists of 100 million entries, and thus are worst methods.

Comment: @chqrlie - linked list can be sorted faster using [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) with O(1) space (for a small (25 to 32 iterators, pointers, references, ...) array).

Comment: @rcgldr: we are on the same page: the small array used by bottom up merge sort has an optimum size of **log(n)**, but most implementations use a fixed size array of 25 to 32 elements, which is fine up to 4 billion elements. **O(1)** and **O(log(n))** are essentially the same in this case.

Comment: @chqrlie - the last element in that small array points to a list of unlimited size, so even with array size set to 32, it can sort a list with more than 4 billion nodes, merging 2 billion nodes at a time into the last list. Rather than adjust the small array size, the max index used for the array can be kept track of when merging nodes into the array, but the speed up when merging the array into a single list is insignificant. The other point is speed, for a large list with scattered nodes, top down merge sort is about 40% slower than bottom up, due to the traversal of sub-lists to split them

Comment: @rcgldr: I am not questioning the choice of algorithm, bottom up merge sort for linked lists is definitely an excellent choice. But if one does not allow for **O(log(n))** extra space, the time complexity will increase for arbitrary large lists, in the case of a 32-element array, this is means list lengths much greater than 4 billion elements and is rather theoretical, but the slow down would be real if you limited the array size to single digit numbers. The theoretical space requirement is **O(log(n))** but in practical cases **O(1)** suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Probably selection sort. It's inefficient compared to the other options, at a time complexity of Ω(n²), as opposed to bubble and insertion sort at Ω(n) and quick and merge sort at Ω(n log(n)).</strike>

As trincot mentioned above, merge sort would be the worst in this circumstance as it uses auxiliary space while the other three algorithms sort inplace.

Comment: Don't bubble sort and insertion sort have time complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is incorrect: selection, bubble and insertion sort all have a a time complexity of Ω(n²), which makes them candidates for the **worst** way to sort a list of 100 million items. Depending on the actual order of the list, thee methods may actually be faster than merge sort or quick sort.